# How to extend widget with all their property

Tags: android, inheritance, flutter, dart, widget

here i have created the class which returns the IconButton widget.

```
class IconBtn extends StatelessWidget {

  const IconBtn({
    Key key,
    this.onPressed,
    this.clr,
    @required this.icon,

  }) : super(key: key);

  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final IconClass icon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return IconButton (
      onPressed: (){},
      color: Colors.red,
      icon: icon,
    );

  }
}
```

then while calling the class i could access only the properties which i have already defined in IconBtn class. i want to use all the properties of IconButton with the extend of another class. suggestions are welcome..!

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return IconBtn (
            icon: IconClass(icon :Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
}
```

Comment: their is no way to access all the properties of IconButton through IconBtn custom class. you have to create all the variables in that class.

Comment: To do this you need to pass an IconButton Widget within your widget.

Answer (score 1):

`IconBtn` is a `StatelessWidget` which has no relation with the `IconButton` class other than it uses it with in it's build function. Each property you see for `IconBtn` is it's constructor parameter, that means, unless you define all the properties of `IconButton` as property of `IconBtn` class, you would not be able to access all the properties of IconButton.

**Note:** Even though if you define all the properties of `IconButton` into the `IconBtn`, they are properties of `IconBtn` class not `IconButton` class, but you can pass those values to the `IconButton` class as you shown in your own example.

One more thing, Flutter is more like composition over inheritance, so your approach is correct. Feel free to add more properties to the IconBtn class if you want.

---

As @huextrat suggested, you may pass the IconButton widget itself as one of the parameter to solve your problem if you really want all the properties of IconButton, but usually we only want just some properties.

Comment: can u give any example of code . i have tried adding the IconButton widget as one of the parameter but i couldn't modify the values. for ex if once i created the widget with colors and icons in new class i can't able to modify it while calling the created class in new place.

Comment: you don't need to modify, simply create the new instance. That is how flutter works.